# bash if statement gives syntax error in console, but works properly

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

Using a bash if statement to check if two numbers in two different arrays are equal. It seems that on the condition where the statement should evaluate to false (ie. the two numbers are not equal) then console displays a syntax error.

Code in question:

```
for((i=0;i<=passes256Size;i+=1));do
    if((${passes212[$i]}==${passes256[$i]})); then
        passesBoth[$i]=${passes256[$i]}     
    fi
done
```

Error:

```
./partii.sh: line 46: 102==: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=")
./partii.sh: line 46: ==103: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==103")
```

The program still runs and gives me the desired result, however I get those two errors coming up during run time. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: try: `if (( ${passes212[$i]} == ${passes256[$i]} ))`. Mind the spaces.

Comment: Tried with the spaces and I still get the same error, however the error now includes the extra spacing around the ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to test two numbers for equality using bash's arithmetic context.  Let's simplify and observe error messages:

```
$ ((2==)) && echo yes
bash: ((: 2==: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==")
$ ((==2)) && echo yes
bash: ((: ==2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==2")
```

The above match fairly closely the error messages that you observe.

The following, of course, works as expected:

```
$ ((2==2)) && echo yes
yes
```

It appears that, depending on which message you observed, that either the value of `${passes212[$i]}` or `${passes256[$i]}` is *empty*.

Let's try this again but using variables with or without assigned values:

```
$ x=2; y=""; (($x==$y)) && echo yes
bash: ((: 2==: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==")
$ x=""; y=2; (($x==$y)) && echo yes
bash: ((: ==2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "==2")
```

If the variable's value is empty, we get the same error messages as above when no variable was present at all.  This would seem to confirm our diagnosis.

The solution is to make sure both arrays have assigned values.

Comment: This was my issue, the arrays were made such that they were different sizes and it would display the error when a particular element was being matched with an empty element. Thank you!